docker COPY nginx usr/share/nginx/html not copied
I built docker image and I copied current directory files into usr/share/nginx/html.
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

And I defined the yaml file to be copied to the volume mounted file.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: suryeon/project3-backend:project
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-volume
              mountPath: "/app/frontend"  
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_HOST
              value: mysql-service 
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: project3
        - name: frontend
          image: suryeon/project3-frontend:project
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-volume
              mountPath: "/app/frontend"
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - |
              echo "Starting to copy files from /usr/share/nginx/html to /app/frontend" &&
              cp -r /usr/share/nginx/html/* /app/frontend &&
              echo "Starting Nginx server" &&
              nginx -g 'daemon off;'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-docker-registry-secret
      volumes:  
        - name: shared-volume
          emptyDir: {} 

But when I checked the mounted directory in the pod, there are only index.html and 50x.html that nginx provides as default. How do I fix this?
PS C:\Users\suryeon\Onedrive\project2-2> kubectl exec -it backend-frontend-6979db74c7-df74n -c frontend -- ls /usr/share/nginx/html
50x.html    index.html


I checked that the file copy is in good condition, and the backend is receiving and rendering this copied file. But the screen is still nginx default screen.

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            root /app/frontend;
            index index.html
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /app/frontend;
        }
    }
}

I modified nginx.conf like this, but it still has problems.

You're copying wrong. Forget everything about Kubernetes and pods just for a second.
docker run --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash suryeon/project3-frontend:project -c "ls -l /usr/share/nginx/html"

If this doesn't list what you copied, then you have a problem, and you should not be using args: in k8s resources to remediate it.
Check your .dockerignore or the folder/context that you are using in docker build and therefore is set as COPY . when you are building the image.

Also, Kubernetes has this little thing called the Nginx Ingress Controller. You therefore don't need to run nginx yourself as a container; busybox-httpd can serve static assets just as well, but so can your api server, such as PHP, Python, NodeJS, etc.

Thank you for your answer. I ran the command you mentioned, and the copied directory files + 50x.html were printed out. But the screen still pops up as the default screen for nginx, is it a nginx setup issue?

In a similar vein, I wouldn't try to use volumes here.  If the backend needs a copy of these files, COPY them into its image as well.

@user28775503 It means you're copying somewhere that isn't the nginx container default site path. Specifically, what do you think root /app/frontend does in the config?
